# Using runtimeArgs --disable-web-security but request still fails: Request had no target IP address space, yet the resource is in address space local

Tags: angular, cors, azure-ad-b2c, private-network-access

I am trying to access a B2C login page from my localhost VScode using angular 12+

I am getting this error:

> Request had no target IP address space, yet the resource is in address space 'local'

[image: Request had no target IP address space, yet the resource is in address space 'local']

In my launch.json file I have:

```
"runtimeArgs": [
                "--disable-web-security"
            ]
```

If I remove the above lines I am not able to connect to my APIs running locally.
Please help to put the right settings in my launch.json

Comment: Not completely sure, but i am facing the same issue and it is related to the latest update in chromium.  98.0.4758.81 (Build oficial) (64 bits)
I changed to another browser, but it also got updated and the error is now on every browser with this chromium version. HTH

Comment: Exactly. It is because of browser updates. The new chromium no more supports debugging. 
I was using Edge for a while but that also stopped working

Comment: @pposada do you have any fixes for this?

Comment: I am currently using old IE to avoid it. but will use the recommendation from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018461/chrome-98-private-network-access-problem-w-disabled-web-security-request-had-n)