# Request blocked by CORS policy after update to Edge 98.0.1108.43: Request had no target IP address space, yet the resource is in address space private

Tags: google-chrome, cors, microsoft-edge, chromium, private-network-access

This problem also happens in Chrome.

Error in console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.x.xxx:xxxx/' from origin
> 'http://xx.xxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request had no
> target IP address space, yet the resource is in address space
> `private`.

My Edge worked fine last month. The problem started to happen after  updating Edge.

The flag `#block-insecure-private-network-requests` is set to disabled.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem without reverting the browser to an old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Similar problem solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018461/chrome-98-private-network-access-problem-w-disabled-web-security-request-had-n)

So for edge, just replace the regedit path

"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome"

to

"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge"

Note that changing this setting will effect all urls.

More secure way is setting another regedit key, which is InsecurePrivateNetworkRequestsAllowedForUrls

Steps:

1. open regedit
2. go to the path "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\InsecurePrivateNetworkRequestsAllowedForUrls" (create if it not exists)
3. add string(REG_SZ), the key should be integers like "1,2,3,...", and the value for each string is the url you want to pass cors policy

E.g.

```
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\InsecurePrivateNetworkRequestsAllowedForUrls\1 = "http://www.example.com:8080"
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\InsecurePrivateNetworkRequestsAllowedForUrls\2 = "[*.]example.edu"
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto Edge with below URL
`edge://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests`

You can disable or enable from here and relaunch browser.

Comment: You didn't get the question. I already set this flag to disabled, but still blocked by cors policy.

Comment: @chyj4747, how did you fix this?